# Retrive all objects from Parse and then print in a Custom TableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I tried everything and I cant solve this, maybe im too tired to see, idk.

What i want is to retrive all objects from parse and list them in a tableview. So each row in the tableview must represent a row in the Parse Class. Objective: Show all the restaurants available.

Right now i can get all the objects from the Parse Class, but shows the same title on all table rows.

Here is the output (as you can see, always show the same name: "Renato" because its the last one that is retrived)

[image]

My code:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class ListaTableViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 3
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> ListaTableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ListaTableViewCell

    var query = PFQuery(className:"Restaurantes")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) Restaurantes.")
            // Do something with the found objects
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {

                    cell.textCell.text = object["nome"] as? String


                        println(object.objectId)

                }
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
        }
    }


    //cell.textCell.text = "Hello world"
    cell.imageBg.image = UIImage(named: "www.maisturismo.jpg")


    return cell
}

}
```

**Println Output**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently iterating through the whole objects array which will show always the last

```
for object in objects {
      cell.textCell.text = object["nome"] as? String
}
```

You need to do it like this

```
if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
      cell.textCell.text = objects[indexPath.row]["nome"] as? String
}
```

Also you should take another "way" of using the UITableViewController Subclass... Take a look, I quickly wired you up some code to see how you should do it...

https://gist.github.com/DennisWeidmann/740cbed1856da856926e

Comment: Hum.. Now shows only the first one that is "Mr.Miagui" on all 3 rows.

Comment: yes it is because you show 3 sections, but only one row in every section... change your sections to 1 and your rows to 3 and it will work... Also take a look at my gist... There I show you how you should do the complete thing

Comment: Thats right :)
I checked your code on github, but gives me an error on line 14 "[AnyObject]?' does not have a member named 'Generator'"

Comment: Yes, sorry I had just coded it on GitHub without Xcode... please take a look at the edited version and look at the for loop... objects is an optional... you have to unwrap it before iterating.... for object in objects!

Comment: We are almost there! But now i get blank rows with no data.

Comment: You will need to code the rest on your own mate... :-) I just gave you an example on how to do it right and to solve your question... I don't know parse and I have no chance to debug your code without the project :-)

Comment: Have you took a look what kind of objects are returned from the closure?

Comment: I managed to get one step forward, but now i get "`Array index out of range`" when i try `cell.textCell.text = queryArray[indexPath.row]["nome"] as? String`
Sorry for the trouble :)

Comment: Well this happens if you try to access an index of an array that is not there... but this is a little bit weird, because if you have set numberOfRowsInSection to the count of the array it couldn't have less entries... have you added, or deleted something in that array?